# Repeater Highlight Item in ItemCommand

Tags: c#, .net, repeater

I have a repeater, which inside I bind some usercontrol with Panel. The panel has a `OnClick` event and raise a `ItemCommand`. I am aware that the `DataItem` is not persist throughout the postback and therefore it will be null during the `ItemCommand` event, my requirement is to change the color of the particular usercontrol when it is clicked (without using Javascript). Anyone has an idea?

Comment: "without using Javascript" why do you wanat to avoid JS.

Comment: _RepeaterCommandEventArgs_ e.Item won't be null in the ItemCommand event of the repeater if you have _EnableViewState="true"_.

Comment: @sajanyamaha it's the requirement

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi EnableViewState is always true and once you post back the repeater will not retain any DataItem, I am talking about DataItem not just e.Item

Comment: But you can find any control placed in repeater, via _e.Item.FindControl("controlid")_. Can't you? Also you get three parameters _e.CommandName_, _e.CommandArgument_, _e.CommandSource_. Pardon me if I am misunderstanding your question or requirement.

Comment: Are you binding the repeater again in Page_Load? I mean have you checked _if(!IsPostBack)_? If not, this could be the reason your dataitem won't be persistent through postbacks.

Comment: I am hoping the answer is not to rebind the data all over again and fix the one just got selected to be highlighted